# Real values of $\frac{\zeta(2 s)}{\zeta(s)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

If $\frac{\zeta(2 s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is a real number, then must $s$ be real ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not.  For example, let $2s$ be any non-real zero of the zeta function where $s$ is not a zero.
Through such a point, there will be a curve along which $\zeta(2z)/\zeta(z)$ is real.

EDIT: Here is a plot of the curve where $\zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$ is real in one region of the plane.  A dot indicates the one non-real point in this region where $\zeta(2s) = 0$.

[image]

Comment: And when that ratio is real but non-null?

Comment: What about it?  Everywhere on the curve except at $s$ where $\zeta(2s)=0$, the ratio is real and nonzero.